# javascript - simple linked list traversal issue

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, traversal

I have implemented a single linked list using javascript. Please find the code below:

```
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.nextElement = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.head === null;
  }

  insertAtHead(data) {
    const tempNode = new Node(data);
    tempNode.nextElement = this.head;
    this.head = tempNode;
  }

  traverse() {
    let current = this.head;
    while (current.nextElement != null) {
      console.log("node data", current.data);
      current = current.nextElement;
    }
  }

  insertAtTail(data) {
    const tempNode = new Node(data);
    if (this.head === null) {
      this.head = tempNode;
      return;
    }

    let currentNode = this.head;
    while (currentNode.nextElement != null) {
      currentNode = currentNode.nextElement;
    }

    currentNode.nextElement = tempNode;
  }
}

const linkedList = new LinkedList();
linkedList.insertAtTail(12);
linkedList.insertAtTail(23);
linkedList.insertAtTail(25);

linkedList.traverse();
```

But the traverse method never prints the last element. What am I missing here? The insertAtTail method looks correct though. Could anyone please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the traverse, you need to check all nodes not until the next one is null.

so I just removed the .nextElement from the traverse and it works fine

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.nextElement = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.head === null;
  }

  insertAtHead(data) {
    const tempNode = new Node(data);
    tempNode.nextElement = this.head;
    this.head = tempNode;
  }

  traverse() {
    let current = this.head;
    while (current) { // Here
      console.log("node data", current.data);
      current = current.nextElement;
    }
  }

  insertAtTail(data) {
    const tempNode = new Node(data);
    if (this.head === null) {
      this.head = tempNode;
      return;
    }

    let currentNode = this.head;
    while (currentNode.nextElement != null) {
      currentNode = currentNode.nextElement;
    }

    currentNode.nextElement = tempNode;
  }
}

const linkedList = new LinkedList();
linkedList.insertAtTail(12);
linkedList.insertAtTail(23);
linkedList.insertAtTail(25);


linkedList.traverse();
```

Answer (score 2):

`traverse` stops its loop when `current.nextElement` is `null` — but at that point, `current` is still a node with `data`, it's just that it doesn't have a **next** node after it.

Instead, keep going until the node, itself, is `null`:

```
traverse() {
  let current = this.head;
  while (current) { // *** Only change is on this line
    console.log("node data", current.data);
    current = current.nextElement;
  }
}
```

(That

```
while (current) {
```

could be

```
while (current !== null) {
```

if you prefer.)

Live Example:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.nextElement = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.head === null;
  }

  insertAtHead(data) {
    const tempNode = new Node(data);
    tempNode.nextElement = this.head;
    this.head = tempNode;
  }

  traverse() {
    let current = this.head;
    while (current) {
      console.log("node data", current.data);
      current = current.nextElement;
    }
  }

  insertAtTail(data) {
    const tempNode = new Node(data);
    if (this.head === null) {
      this.head = tempNode;
      return;
    }

    let currentNode = this.head;
    while (currentNode.nextElement != null) {
      currentNode = currentNode.nextElement;
    }

    currentNode.nextElement = tempNode;
  }
}

const linkedList = new LinkedList();
linkedList.insertAtTail(12);
linkedList.insertAtTail(23);
linkedList.insertAtTail(25);

linkedList.traverse();
```